# Two columns with one loop

Tags: php, loops, for-loop, laravel-blade

I have two columns with two loops, **but I need only one loop** and still have two columns. When loop count is more than 5 make new column and continue.

This is my code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
        <ul class="list-group">
            @for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
              //code
            @endfor
        </ul>
    </div>
```

and this

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
        <ul class="list-group">
            @for ($i = 5; $i < 10; $i++)
              //code
            @endfor
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Any solution please ? 
Thank you.

Comment: [%](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.arithmetic.php) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you need to put your loop in a separate file for ex. `loop.blade.php`
And your content would be like this.

**loop.blade.php**

```
<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">
    <ul class="list-group">
        @for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
          //code for $column
        @endfor
    </ul>
</div>
```

**yourfile.blade.php**

```
<div class="row">
    @include('loop', ['column' => $yourFirstColumn])

    ........
```

And this

```
<div class="row">
    @include('loop', ['column' => $yourSecondColumn])

    ........
```

Comment: Welcome, Marking answers as right helps others to know right answer easily and encourages us to do more effort to help people on this site

Answer (score 0):

make column width value in php conditional variable. If result less than or equals to 5 col-lg-12 else col-lg-6 like this:

```
<?php
        @for ($i = 0; $i < 5; $i++)
    if($i <= 5){
        $col-lg = "col-lg-12";
    }else{
        $col-lg = "col-lg-6";
    }
?>
    <span class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 <?php echo $col-lg;?>">
<?php
          //code
        @endfor
?>
    </span>
 //end loop here
```

Comment: Thank you very much. But I need a one loop thats split column when loop count is more than 5. Make another one `<div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-6">`